# Having Trouble Understanding and Converting this JQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am a relatively new JavaScript programmer and I am trying to make an AJAX Node JS file upload system. I found a snippet which is supposed to work to send the AJAX request to the Node server. I have no experience in JQuery and the code is written with it. If anyone could help me convert this to normal JS that would be great. Even help understanding it's inner workings could be helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File upload Node.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm"
         enctype="multipart/form-data"
         action="/api/photo"
         method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js">    </script>
<script>
  //AJAX CODE STARTS HERE (uses JQuery Form)
  $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {

        $(this).ajaxSubmit({

            error: function(xhr) {
                    status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
            },

            success: function(response) {
                      console.log(response);
            }
        });
        //Very important line, it disable the page refresh.
        return false;
     });    
  });
</script>
</html>
```

I didn't feel including the Node JS server side code was necessary as all it does is take the request and use the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) module to process and upload the file. Any help is welcome.

Thanks,
Cameron

**EDIT:** Also, if anyone has an idea to streamline a Node JS file upload within normal JavaScript without a page reload, that would be great.

Comment: so you want ajax call in pure javascript right ?

Comment: @KevalBhatt That is correct, but I don't understand what the jquery specifically does to send the correct request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("uploadForm").onsubmit = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();  //Very important line, it disable the page refresh.

    var f = e.target,
        formData = new FormData(f),
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", f.action);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
       if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) // means success
       {
          console.log(response);
       }else{ // may mean error, check appropriate status and readyState for error
          status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
       }
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Sources:
for help on `onreadystatechange`, `readystate` and `status` http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

for pure javascript form send
http://www.sitepoint.com/easier-ajax-html5-formdata-interface/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly you're using the jQuery form plugin. You can see the source here: https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js

Note that your use case is using file uploads so the relevant code is in the fileUploadXhr function

```
    // XMLHttpRequest Level 2 file uploads (big hat tip to francois2metz)
function fileUploadXhr(a) {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(a[i].name, a[i].value);
    }

    if (options.extraData) {
        var serializedData = deepSerialize(options.extraData);
        for (i=0; i < serializedData.length; i++) {
            if (serializedData[i]) {
                formdata.append(serializedData[i][0], serializedData[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
    . . .
```

FormData is the object provided by browsers to help process your file upload in modern browsers.

Comment: Could you explain how to utilize this in my case? I still don't understand how to get this to work with the setup I have.